# Convert Javascript new Date().getTime(); into a R recognised timestamp (ideally with lubridate)

Tags: r, lubridate

If I open the Javascript console and type:

```
new Date().getTime();
```

I get:
1607534517803

I have a data frame in R with timestamps of this format. I'd like to convert this into a meaningful datetime.

Tried:

```
lubridate::as_datetime(1607534517803)
[1] "52910-09-28 14:03:23 UTC"
```

Expected today's date and time (At the time of posting, 12/9/20 at 11:24am USA central time)

How can I return a meaningful timestamp in R?

Comment: Could you please check if this works for you? `as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(1607534517803/1000,origin = "1960-01-01")`

Comment: Or this `as.POSIXct(1607534517803/1000,origin = "1960-01-01")`

Comment: They both work and return the correct result!

Comment: Would you be comfortable of adding them as solutions so that you can accept?

Comment: I would be yes but want to hold it open for a few minutes. Was hoping to see a safe and familiar lubridate method

Comment: For sure, I will add them so that they can help others and then you can make a decision :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of these options:

```
#Code1
as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(1607534517803/1000,origin = "1960-01-01")

#Code2
as.POSIXct(1607534517803/1000,origin = "1960-01-01")
```

The OP solution (many thanks for hard working):

```
#Code2
strtime_to_dt <- function(x) {   as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x) / 1000, origin = "1960-01-01", formats = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS") }
```

Comment: Using this method actually returns a ts to the second level. I need the milliseconds peserved too :/

Comment: Got it with `strtime_to_dt <- function(x) {
  as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x) / 1000, origin = "1960-01-01", formats = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
}`

Comment: @DougFir Fantastic job!

Comment: @DougFir I updated the solution with the code you shared and for sure credits to you. Many thanks for the effort!

Comment: I'm going loopy. I swear this was working earlier but now it's not. Posted another similar Q over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65226194/convert-a-unixtime-into-a-datetime-that-keeps-milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as_datetime` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
 as_datetime(1607534517803/1000,origin = "1960-01-01")
 #[1] "2010-12-09 17:21:57 UTC"
```

Comment: Isn;t that only at the second level though? Need the milliseconds too

Comment: @DougFir I find the accepted answer also have that

Comment: Although this does answer the Q