# Convert a unixtime into a datetime that keeps milliseconds

Tags: r

I'm working with some timestamps:

```
pageviews$timestamp %>% head()
[1] "1605859226452" "1605859226461" "1605859248803" "1605859261112" "1605859283839" "1605859471370"
```

I need to convert these to datetimes and preserve to the most granular level possible, I think milliseconds.

Tried earlier using as.POSIXct:

```
strtime_to_dt <- function(x) {
  as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x) / 1000, origin = "1960-01-01", formats = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
}

x <- pageviews$timestamp %>% head() # same data as above
> strtime_to_dt(x)
[1] "2010-11-20 08:00:26 UTC" "2010-11-20 08:00:26 UTC" "2010-11-20 08:00:48 UTC" "2010-11-20 08:01:01 UTC" "2010-11-20 08:01:23 UTC"
[6] "2010-11-20 08:04:31 UTC"
```

This returns datetimes at the second level. How can I get it at the millisecond level?

(Would be great if doable in tidyverse or lubridate, but I'll take anything)

EDIT based on comments
some timestamps:

```
 x
      timestamp
1 1605859226452
2 1605859226461
3 1605859248803
4 1605859261112
5 1605859283839
6 1605859471370
```

Updated function:

```
strtime_to_dt <- function(x) {format(strtime_to_dt(x), "%F %H:%M:%OS3")}

strtime_to_dt(x)
Error: C stack usage  7969908 is too close to the limit
```

Adding sessionInfo()

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.8.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C              LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] DBI_1.1.0              jsonlite_1.7.1         googleAnalyticsR_0.8.0 lubridate_1.7.9        forcats_0.5.0         
 [6] stringr_1.4.0          dplyr_1.0.2            purrr_0.3.4            readr_1.4.0            tidyr_1.1.2           
[11] tibble_3.0.4           ggplot2_3.3.2          tidyverse_1.3.0       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tinytex_0.27      tidyselect_1.1.0  xfun_0.19         haven_2.3.1       gargle_0.5.0      colorspace_1.4-1  vctrs_0.3.4      
 [8] generics_0.1.0    utf8_1.1.4        blob_1.2.1        rlang_0.4.8       pillar_1.4.6      withr_2.3.0       glue_1.4.2       
[15] bit64_4.0.5       dbplyr_2.0.0      modelr_0.1.8      readxl_1.3.1      lifecycle_0.2.0   munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.3.0     
[22] cellranger_1.1.0  rvest_0.3.6       memoise_1.1.0     curl_4.3          fansi_0.4.1       broom_0.7.2       Rcpp_1.0.5       
[29] openssl_1.4.3     backports_1.2.0   scales_1.1.1      fs_1.5.0          bit_4.0.4         googleAuthR_1.3.1 askpass_1.1      
[36] hms_0.5.3         digest_0.6.27     stringi_1.5.3     grid_4.0.3        odbc_1.3.0        cli_2.1.0         tools_4.0.3      
[43] magrittr_1.5      pacman_0.5.1      crayon_1.3.4      pkgconfig_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.1    xml2_1.3.2        reprex_0.3.0     
[50] assertthat_0.2.1  httr_1.4.2        rstudioapi_0.11   R6_2.5.0          compiler_4.0.3
```

Comment: You can specify `OS3`

Comment: Hi @akrun, OK... where? How?!

Comment: Tried changing `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"` to `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3"` and `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:OS"` neither of those did the trick

Comment: If you need to show the output as a character, you may use `strftime` or `format` and it would show the milliseconds

Comment: You can check `str1 <- "1605859226452"; format(strtime_to_dt(str1), "%F %H:%M:%OS3")
[1] "2010-11-20 02:00:26.451"`

Comment: That gives `Error: unexpected string constant in " format(strtime_to_dt(str1), "%F %H:%M:%OS3") "2010-11-20 02:00:26.451""`

Comment: The code is `format(strtime_to_dt(str1), "%F %H:%M:%OS3")`

Comment: @akrun I tried your function, but please see my edits. Getting 'Error: C stack usage  7969908 is too close to the limit'

Comment: Do you have a character string as showed in the first line

Comment: I tried converting to  character: `x <- as.character(x)
> x
[1] "c(\"1605859226452\", \"1605859226461\", \"1605859248803\", \"1605859261112\", \"1605859283839\", \"1605859471370\")"
> strtime_to_dt(1605859226452)
Error: C stack usage  7969908 is too close to the limit
> strtime_to_dt('1605859226452')
Error: C stack usage  7969908 is too close to the limit`

Comment: You may need `as.character(x$timestamp)`

Comment: You should be able to use `strtime_to_dt <- function(x) format(as.POSIXct(x / 1000, origin = "1960-01-01"), format = "%F %H:%M:%OS3")` (although this of course returns a character string of a date and not an actual date object).

Comment: @DougFir Can you check the solution I posted.  It works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
format(strtime_to_dt(as.character(x$timestamp)), "%F %H:%M:%OS3") 
#[1] "2010-11-20 02:00:26.451" "2010-11-20 02:00:26.460" "2010-11-20 02:00:48.802" "2010-11-20 02:01:01.111" "2010-11-20 02:01:23.838"
#[6] "2010-11-20 02:04:31.369"
```

#### data

```
x <- structure(list(timestamp = c(1605859226452, 1605859226461, 1605859248803, 
1605859261112, 1605859283839, 1605859471370)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: HI, tried: `x <- pageviews$timestamp %>% head
> x
[1] "1605859226452" "1605859226461" "1605859248803" "1605859261112" "1605859283839" "1605859471370"
> format(strtime_to_dt(as.character(x)), "%F %H:%M:%OS3") 
Error: C stack usage  7972244 is too close to the limit`

Comment: @DougFir never mind, it is working correctly for me.

Comment: :( I tried using the structure(list... too and got the same error. Guess it's unique to my set up

Comment: @DougFir can you try on a fresh R session.  I am using R 4.0.3 on Mac

Comment: Yes will try a fresh session now. I posted sessionInfo() too

Comment: @DougFir Do you get the same error with `strtime_to_dt(as.character(x$timestamp))`

Comment: Yes, same error with `strtime_to_dt(as.character(x$timestamp))`

Comment: Fresh session:
1) `pageviews %>% head() %>% pull(timestamp) %>% dput
c("1605859226452", "1605859226461", "1605859248803", "1605859261112", 
"1605859283839", "1605859471370")`

Comment: 2) the function: `strtime_to_dt <- function(x) {format(strtime_to_dt(x), "%F %H:%M:%OS3")}` (seems it's already chr so removed as.char but did try that variation

Comment: @DougFir I get `v1 <- c("1605859226452", "1605859226461", "1605859248803", "1605859261112",  "1605859283839", "1605859471370"); 
format(strtime_to_dt(v1), "%F %H:%M:%OS3") 
[1] "2010-11-20 02:00:26.451" "2010-11-20 02:00:26.460" "2010-11-20 02:00:48.802" "2010-11-20 02:01:01.111" "2010-11-20 02:01:23.838"
[6] "2010-11-20 02:04:31.369"`

Comment: 3) `y <- pageviews %>% head() %>% pull(timestamp)
> y
[1] "1605859226452" "1605859226461" "1605859248803" "1605859261112" "1605859283839" "1605859471370"`
Then `strtime_to_dt(y)
Error: C stack usage  7972356 is too close to the limit`

Comment: `v1 <- c("1605859226452", "1605859226461", "1605859248803", "1605859261112",  "1605859283839", "1605859471370")
> format(strtime_to_dt(v1), "%F %H:%M:%OS3")
Error: C stack usage  7974692 is too close to the limit`

Comment: It may be something related to your OS as I can't reproduce it

Comment: Thanks for trying all the same. Accepting since your answer clearly works, just not on my OS